# Map of $z$ to $z^4$ given $\Re(z) + \Im(z) ≥0$ and $\Re(z)< 0$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm having trouble finding the range of $z\mapsto z^4 | \Re(z) + \Im(z) ≥0\text{ and }\Re(z)< 0 $. If I set $z=x+iy$ and let $x+y=0$, I get:  $z^4= (x+iy)^2 = (x-ix)^4 = x^4(1-i)^4 = x^4(-2i)^2 = -4x^4$.

Since $x$ is real, this tells me the line $x+y=0$ maps to the negative real axis. What I have trouble doing now is filling the rest of the region. Since $\Re(z) + \Im(z) ≥0$ and $\Re(z)<0$ represents all complex numbers between of argument between $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$, then $z^4$ would have arguments between $3\pi$ and $2\pi$ which looks like the top half of the plane. I however can't decide on its shape or what it looks like. Does it really just cover the entire half of the plane? If so, how do I show that? In sum, I am looking for a more systematic way of determining the rest of this mapping so that I can apply it to other problems of this type, thanks!

Comment: For nonzero $z$ with $\Re z+\Im z \ge 0$, note that $-\frac{\pi}{4}\le\arg z\le\frac{3\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Therefore (multiplying this arg by 4) the range is the whole plane.

Comment: @AnneBauval, I've added a condition so it's not so trivial, could you give some tips on the new question?

Comment: Now $\frac{\pi}2\le\arg z\le\frac{3\pi}{4}$. Therefore (multiplying this arg by 4) the range is the (closed) upper half plane.